# Udev Block iPhone

Tags: udev, iphone

I'm trying to block my iPhone from being used when I connect it so that I can pass it through to a VM. So far, I have this udev rule but I still get an error about the device being used whenever I try and pass it through.

```
blacklist ipheth
blacklist apple-mfi-fastcharge
install ipheth /bin/false
install apple-mfi-fastcharge /bin/false
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05ac", ATTRS{idProduct}=="12a8", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

As you can see, I have tried to deauth using the vendor and product IDs as well as disable the two modules mentioned in dmesg.

This is all I get from dmesg now. Which would indicate that what I've got is at least somewhat working, as there's no ipheth or fast charging.

```
Jan 21 19:56:44 carbon-14 kernel: usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Jan 21 19:56:45 carbon-14 kernel: usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=12a8, bcdDevice=16.01
Jan 21 19:56:45 carbon-14 kernel: usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 21 19:56:45 carbon-14 kernel: usb 1-3: Product: iPhone
Jan 21 19:56:45 carbon-14 kernel: usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Jan 21 19:56:45 carbon-14 kernel: usb 1-3: SerialNumber: xxx
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

You've probably missed `usbmuxd`.

In `systemd`-based distributions, it is now configured as a static service, and udev is configured to tag any Apple iDevices with `TAG+="systemd"` and `ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="usbmuxd.service"`, which causes `systemd` to start `usbmuxd.service` whenever such a device is plugged in.

Since it is a static service, `systemctl disable` does nothing to it. You'll want `systemctl mask usbmuxd.service` instead.

Comment: Yup, that's got me a different error at least, so progress! I get "Error resetting device: LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND" now

Comment: Was that error from the VM, or still on the host side of things? It seems like something is trying to invoke a `libusb`-based configuration tool. Maybe an `udev`rule invoking `usb_modeswitch`?

Comment: That error occurs when I attempt to redirect the USB device using SPICE